# Using ViewFlipper to change views with motion event

Tags: java, android, viewflipper, motionevent

I am not sure really how to explain this, but this video will hopefully explain a little. [here](https://tune.pk/video/3374542/android-code-view-flipper)

I'm trying to get something similar to that, but to when the screen moves with your finger.

EX: I slide my finger to the left a little bit, the view moves with my finger and displays part of the next screen.

This is the current code I have for the viewflipper, which just changes view on swipe.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
    switch(e.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1=e.getX();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2=e.getX();
            float deltax = x2-x1;
            if(Math.abs(deltax)>MIN_DISTANCE){
                if(x2>x1){
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                }else{
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Have you got the answer?